# How to update pygame window display after condition is met?

Tags: python, pygame

I have some code for a pygame window:

```
while True:
    try:
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    except Exception:
        pass 

    a=button("Enter",100,150,100,50,darkgreen,green,"play")
    button("Exit",450,150,100,50,darkred,red,"quit")

    for event in pygame.event.get() :
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT :
            pygame.quit()
    pygame.display.update()
    #if a == False:
        #pygame.quit()
```

it displays 2 buttons (created by the button function) which can be clicked. When the green button is clicked a tkinter input box appears. After the user inputs the necessary things and inputs are confirmed valid the function returns the state (if false user has entered details correctly). After this happens i want to change what the window is displaying and show something completelty different. The original purpose of "a" (the state) was to close the window and open a new window once inputs were verified, however after researching i found out you cannot open two windows in the same script.

I tried this:

```
if a == False:
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        gameDisplay.blit(image1, (50, 0))
        gameDisplay.blit(image2, (50, 100))
        gameDisplay.blit(image3, (50, 200))
        gameDisplay.blit(image4, (50, 300))
        gameDisplay.blit(image5, (120, 100))
        gameDisplay.blit(image6, (120, 200))
        gameDisplay.blit(image7, (130, 260))
        gameDisplay.blit(image8, (130, 290))
        gameDisplay.blit(image9, (130, 320))
        gameDisplay.blit(text, (0,0))
        gameDisplay.blit(text2, (200,385))
        gameDisplay.blit(text3, (200,369))
        gameDisplay.blit(text4, (300,25))
        gameDisplay.blit(text5, (300,100))
        gameDisplay.blit(image16, (300, 45))
        gameDisplay.blit(image17, (350, 45))
        gameDisplay.blit(text6, (300, 170))
        gameDisplay.blit(image10, (300, 120))
        gameDisplay.blit(image11, (350, 120))
        gameDisplay.blit(image12, (400, 120))
        gameDisplay.blit(image13, (450, 120))
        gameDisplay.blit(image14, (500, 120))
        gameDisplay.blit(image15, (550, 120))
        gameDisplay.blit(image19, (300, 190))
        gameDisplay.blit(image20, (350, 190))
        pygame.display.update()
```

and placed it after the second button function but did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: The program isn't formatted correctly with regard to the indentation.  It looks like you are recreating the buttons on every iteration of the main loop, which is probably incorrect too.

Comment: @RufusVS it was just the way i had pasted the code. I fixed it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Pygame, try to stay in a single loop. Based on the condition, show the buttons or play the game.

Try this code:

```
a = True  # show buttons
while True:        
    try:
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    except Exception:
        pass  

    if a == True:  # keep showing buttons until user clicks one
        a=button("Enter",100,150,100,50,darkgreen,green,"play")
        button("Exit",450,150,100,50,darkred,red,"quit")
        
    if a == False:  # run game
            gameDisplay.fill(white)
            gameDisplay.blit(image1, (50, 0))
            ...........
            gameDisplay.blit(image19, (300, 190))
            gameDisplay.blit(image20, (350, 190))
            
    for event in pygame.event.get() :
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT :
            pygame.quit()
    pygame.display.update()
    #if a == False:
        #pygame.quit()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: This works however it only shows the new content for half a second before switching back to the buttons. I put the "a = True" , outside of the while loop and it worked